# Pycall throws ValidationError

Tags: python, asterisk, voip, python-sip, pycall

I'm trying to run these lines of code in `atom` and `python3.6` :

```
from pycall import CallFile, Call, Application
import sys


def call():
        c = Call('SIP/200')
        a = Application('Playback', 'hello-world')
        cf = CallFile(c, a)
        cf.spool()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        call()
```

But I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pd/gits/voiphone/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    call()
  File "/home/pd/gits/voiphone/main.py", line 9, in call
    cf.spool()
  File "/home/pd/telephonerelayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycall/callfile.py", line 135, in spool
    self.writefile()
  File "/home/pd/telephonerelayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycall/callfile.py", line 123, in writefile
    f.write(self.contents)
  File "/home/pd/telephonerelayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycall/callfile.py", line 118, in contents
    return '\n'.join(self.buildfile())
  File "/home/pd/telephonerelayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycall/callfile.py", line 100, in buildfile
    raise ValidationError
pycall.errors.ValidationError
```

I would appreciate if you help me solving my problem.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for the validity check](https://github.com/rdegges/pycall/blob/master/pycall/callfile.py#L66), it appears like the only check that could be catching you out is the one that verifies the spool directory. By default this is set to `/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing` but can be changed when you create the callfile:

```
cf = CallFile(c, a, spool_dir='/my/asterisk/spool/outgoing')
```